# Lock Screen Advertisement App on iPhone iOS Apple iAds Guidelines

Tags: iphone, swift, ios9, iad

I have recently completed a project on android wherein we show deals and ads based on user gps location. DealOut (http://dealout.gr/).  I want to make the same app on iPhone too but I was wondering how can I have lock screen ads on iOS. Also since I won't be using Apple iAds platform i am afraid that my app might get rejected. I have to show Ads that are published by advertiser in the backend and there will be deals that users will earn by watching these ads. Please see android app to get more idea.

I found similar apps on iOS  : coupon dunia and olx. They both show ads but are not using Apple iAds.

So my question is related to Apple iAds Guidelines whether they'll accept it or not.

Also, One possible way of implementing Lock screen Ads on iOS i could think of is to use the music player functionality to show the Ads as album art and probably play audio Ads. Is it possible to have such an app pass the Apple Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how can I have lock screen ads on iOS

Not **ads**; that would be super annoying. Your app *may* show push notification previews on the lock screen, but ultimately that's up to the user's preferences (the user may allow or disallow it on a per-app basis).

> Also since I won't be using Apple iAds platform i am afraid that my
>   app might get rejected

No. You can use other advertisement platforms such as AdMob; Last time I checked, Apple does not prohibit that.